# Script on server to interact with clients Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, shell, client-server

I currently have a javascript library that is using a JSON file to print them on the screen in an interactive way. (::We are using D3JS Library)

When we are on a client, we can easily delete, edit and create some nodes, that are updated in the JSON every 5-10 seconds.

The problem comes from two main facts :

- First the automatic function that call itself every x seconds could make data corruption if we are doing some stuff on the datas already represented on the screen.
- Then the project has been made in order to permit 5 people to interact together. When they are present onto the same session we cannot decently make them refresh every 5 seconds, that cause many overhead and doesn't avoid data corruption.

We have mainly thought about a solution only made with javascript and some AJAX but we realize that it should be reconsidered with a trigger that inform the client that the datas are no longer OK.

We are thinking currently about opening a script onto a server in order to attribute on each client an ID.

The goal would be to detect the modification done on the JSON file (on the server). But the point where we are stuck is :

1) Is there a best scripting language to interact server/web?
2) Which type of things should we use to make the clients update their datas? (socket right?)

About the second point the easiest way would be to call a JS function be we aren't aware of the possibilities given by the shell codes...

Sorry about the fact that we are happy developpers but maybe not enough skilled to solve this problem.

Thanks for your helps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using pure javascript with the new WebSocket feature.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Edit:

WebSocket is a web technology providing full-duplex communications channels over a single TCP connection. The WebSocket API is being standardized by the W3C, and the WebSocket protocol has been standardized by the IETF as RFC 6455.

WebSocket is designed to be implemented in web browsers and web servers, but it can be used by any client or server application. The WebSocket Protocol is an independent TCP-based protocol. Its only relationship to HTTP is that its handshake is interpreted by HTTP servers as an Upgrade request.[1] The WebSocket protocol makes possible more interaction between a browser and a web site, facilitating live content and the creation of real-time games. This is made possible by providing a standardized way for the server to send content to the browser without being solicited by the client, and allowing for messages to be passed back and forth while keeping the connection open.

Comment: Thanks a lot gustavodidomenico! , I'll work on it and give some feedbacks on this thread if I do succeed or in contrary if I fail with that!

Comment: Good luck! Tell us if you have any issues...;)